# onClickListener and Json object

Tags: android, json

So, i have JSON object, and trying to parse it, and create views. The problem appears, when i try to put `books_var.id` into putExtra - its **always** last id from JSON. But in this activity everything looks great.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     int len = explrObject   .length();
     for (int j=0;j<len;j++){
          books_var.id     = explrObject.getString("id").toString();
     }


    llVer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getBaseContext())) {
                Intent ReaderIntent = new Intent(BOOKSActivity.this, READERActivity.class);
                ReaderIntent.putExtra("book", books_var.id);
                BOOKSActivity.this.startActivity(ReaderIntent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

here is JSON:

```
{
    "books": [{
        "id": "3",
        "name": "book",
        "author": "author",
        "image": "tmp\/newcovers\/3n.jpg",
        "level": "level",
        "pages": "100"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "book",
        "author": "author",
        "image": "tmp\/newcovers\/4n.jpg",
        "level": "level",
        "pages": "100"
    }, {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "book",
        "author": "author",
        "image": "tmp\/newcovers\/12n.jpg",
        "level": "level",
        "pages": "100"
    }, {
        "id": "154",
        "name": "book",
        "author": "author",
        "image": "tmp\/newcovers\/3n.jpg",
        "level": "level",
        "pages": "100"
    }, {
        "id": "155",
        "name": "book",
        "author": "author",
        "image": "tmp\/newcovers\/155n.jpg",
        "level": "level",
        "pages": "100"
    }, {
        "id": "169",
        "name": "book",
        "author": "author",
        "image": "tmp\/newcovers\/169n.jpg",
        "level": "level",
        "pages": "100"
    }, {
        "id": "170",
        "name": "book",
        "author": "author",
        "image": "tmp\/newcovers\/170n.jpg",
        "level": "level",
        "pages": "100"
    }]
}
```

[image]

Comment: because books_var.id it take last value in for loop you can take array store it.

Comment: Can you post the JSON that you are trying to parse here?

Comment: @DevanshKumar done

Answer (score 0):

Because every time id overrite to old id you can take one array and store all the id like below ..

```
       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        int len = explrObject.length();
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            books_var.id = explrObject.getString("id").toString();
            idList.add(books_var.id);
        }
    }
    for(int id:idList){
        Log.d("ID::",""+id);
    }
```

Comment: I added picture where i put IDs in Textarea, and it doesnt seem like IDs are overwritten (otherwise pictures and other text would be overwritten as well). But I have a problem only when ID is inside putExtra method.

Comment: intent in it is outside of for loop then it getting only last value.

Comment: There are 2 for loops:
first - to parse book, second to get data about this book, like id, tite etc.
intent is inside of first loop - it has to be that way

Maybe I understand something wrong, but 2 loops work like this:

`for (bookData:book) {
   for (bookData) {
     id = bookData.id;
     title = bookData.title;
   }
//create view with id and title;
}`

Comment: you want when user click on item that time pass id.

Comment: you used list view to show record and make adapter for that then pl add adapter code..

Answer (score 0):

You can use View class methods [setTag(Object tag)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) and [getTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag())

Also there is no need of inner loop for initialising `books_var.id`

Currently in your code `books_var.id` is getting initialised with last book id in json array. So when you click on any row it ends up getting the last book id. Using `setTag` method you can assign different book id value to each row view element and when you get the same view object in `OnClickListener` you can get the book id from `view.getTag()`

Below code will solve your problem

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
 JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
 String bookId = explrObject.optString("id");
 llVer.setTag(bookId);
 llVer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getTag() != null && InternetConnection.checkConnection(getBaseContext())) {
            Intent ReaderIntent = new Intent(BOOKSActivity.this, READERActivity.class);
            ReaderIntent.putExtra("book", v.getTag());
            BOOKSActivity.this.startActivity(ReaderIntent);
        }
    }
  });
}
```